# Resolving dupes of comparing unordered lists in Python

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I found 4 questions that are pretty much duplicates of each other, although the first one is questionably different:

- [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python)
- [Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal)
- [Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866652/determine-if-2-lists-have-the-same-elements-regardless-of-order)
- [How to assert two list contain the same elements in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813633/how-to-assert-two-list-contain-the-same-elements-in-python)

There may be others, but those are the ones that came up when I Googled it.

Due to Python inexperience, lack of sleep (and despite excessive caffeine intake) I'm having trouble deciding how to handle all these.

So, I'm just throwing them out there. If anybody has any suggestions, or wants to just do it, there they are.

Comment: I closed these, choosing the first over the second (where the tie was for me) as the canonical: answerer is a CPython core dev and presents 3 effective approaches.

Comment: @Jim, the correct way would have been to add an answer here and then go on to hammer those. But anyway, as it's done, do feel free to add an answer highlighting your views.

Comment: Was planning but had to take the dog for her walk @BhargavRao :-) . I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to go ahead and close these duplicates.

Now, the rationale behind keeping the Q&A from [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python) was:

- It presents 3 solutions, all mentioned in the other answers without mentioning `set` which might confuse new-comers wanting to compare lists with duplicate elements.
- The presentation is ordered by complexity, giving an insightful metric that many people require.
- The user who answered just happens to be the most *authoritative* source on (C)Python collections since he develops them :-) (at least the `collections` module).

I stumbled when trying to decide if Q&A:2 ([Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal)) should be the canonical because of the *views* it amassed and the *votes* it got; in the end I decided for Q&A:1 since quality **beats** exposure in my eyes (This could, of course, be wrong).

Comment: Seems legit. Quality always beats exposure. Exposure will catch up on the dupe target, because Google. I didn't pick #1 because `set(x) == set(y)` wasn't presented as an answer, because the problem domain was a little different in that question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of deciding:

1. Pick the oldest one.
2. Pick the highest-scoring one.
3. Pick the one with the most views.
4. Pick the one with the most duplicates in /questions/linked/questionID (thanks @BhargovRao!)
5. Evaluate the <s>three</s> four above and pick the one that wins the most.
6. Go to [random.org](http://random.org) and use it to pick one.
7. Post on Meta and let Meta-effect/gold tag badge holders decide.

Let's go through them one by one.

### Oldest

1. 10/19/11 ⭐️
2. 3/8/12
3. 10/10/12
4. 1/15/12

### Highest Score

1. 46
2. 115 ⭐️
3. 57
4. 59

### Most Views

1. 21859
2. 104973 ⭐️
3. 31574
4. 32254

### Most Duplicates Linked

1. 1
2. 3 ⭐️
3. 2
4. 0

### Most of Above Rounds

1. 1
2. 3 ⭐️
3. 0
4. 0

### Random/Arbitrary

random.org gives me 4.

### Let Meta-Effect/Gold Badge Holders Decide

<s>Dunno. Though anyone with a gold [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag badge is welcome to comment on this answer :)</s>
I observe that the last 3 have all been dupehammered to the first.